# Facebook Twitter Buttons with Turbolink

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, turbolinks

I'm trying to implement 2 Share buttons. The `Facebook Like Button` and the `Twitter Share Button`.

But i'm having a problem with turbolinks.. After looking it up i found an [interesting article](http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/facebook.html).

The solution stated that by removing the initial script from the application.html.erb and including the below file will fix the problem.

```
fb_root = null
fb_events_bound = false

$ ->
  loadFacebookSDK()
  bindFacebookEvents() unless fb_events_bound

bindFacebookEvents = ->
  $(document)
    .on('page:fetch', saveFacebookRoot)
    .on('page:change', restoreFacebookRoot)
    .on('page:load', ->
      FB?.XFBML.parse()
    )
  fb_events_bound = true

saveFacebookRoot = ->
  fb_root = $('#fb-root').detach()

restoreFacebookRoot = ->
  if $('#fb-root').length > 0
    $('#fb-root').replaceWith fb_root
  else
    $('body').append fb_root

loadFacebookSDK = ->
  window.fbAsyncInit = initializeFacebookSDK
  $.getScript("//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1")

initializeFacebookSDK = ->
  FB.init
    appId     : 'YOUR_APP_ID'
    channelUrl: '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html'
    status    : true
    cookie    : true
    xfbml     : true
```

The Same goes for the [Twitter Problem](http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/twitter.html):

```
twttr_events_bound = false

$ ->
  bindTwitterEventHandlers() unless twttr_events_bound

bindTwitterEventHandlers = ->
  $(document).on 'page:load', renderTweetButtons
  twttr_events_bound = true

renderTweetButtons = ->
  $('.twitter-share-button').each ->
    button = $(this)
    button.attr('data-url', document.location.href) unless button.data('url')?
    button.attr('data-text', document.title) unless button.data('text')?  
  twttr.widgets.load()
```

I done that, but for some reason my problem isn't going away.. Could someone help me get this right ?

Comment: I take it you are putting in all of the correct information with the fill-ins?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this question [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links) (the answer with the most votes), so try:

```
ready = ->

  ...your coffeescript goes here...

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

I got an issues before with turbolink, while I load fb script in the homepage, and follow the link to another page, and the fb script doesn't reload. So I try to add `data-turbolink-track = false` and it worked.
Hope this help.